# What exactly does the .join() method do?

Tags: python, list, string

I'm pretty new to Python and am completely confused by `.join()` which I have read is the preferred method for concatenating strings.

I tried:

```
strid = repr(595)
print array.array('c', random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 20 - len(strid)))
    .tostring().join(strid)
```

and got something like:

```
5wlfgALGbXOahekxSs9wlfgALGbXOahekxSs5
```

Why does it work like this?  Shouldn't the `595` just be automatically appended?

Comment: I think you tapped your Yubikey while the program was running

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Look carefully at your output:

```
5wlfgALGbXOahekxSs9wlfgALGbXOahekxSs5
^                 ^                 ^
```

I've highlighted the "5", "9", "5" of your original string. The Python [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method is a string method, and takes a *list* of things to join with the string. A simpler example might help explain:

```
>>> ",".join(["a", "b", "c"])
'a,b,c'
```

The "," is inserted between each element of the given list. In your case, your "list" is the string representation "595", which is treated as the list ["5", "9", "5"].

It appears that you're looking for `+` instead:

```
print array.array('c', random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 20 - len(strid)))
.tostring() + strid
```

Comment: Why is it not:
5wlfgALGbXOahekxSs9wlfgALGbXOahekxSs5wlfgALGbXOahekxSs ?
With the string appended to the last element?

Comment: One reason is this gives `join` the useful property of being the inverse of `split` (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: If you want another delimiter, put an empty string at the end of your list. `','.join(['a', 'b', 'c', ''])` gives "a,b,c,"

Comment: OP was probably confusing `string.join` with `os.path.join` which indeed concatenates paths

Answer (score 96):

`join` takes an iterable thing as an argument.  Usually it's a list.  The problem in your case is that a string is itself iterable, giving out each character in turn. Your code breaks down to this:

```
"wlfgALGbXOahekxSs".join("595")
```

which acts the same as this:

```
"wlfgALGbXOahekxSs".join(["5", "9", "5"])
```

and so produces your string:

```
"5wlfgALGbXOahekxSs9wlfgALGbXOahekxSs5"
```

Strings as iterables is one of the most confusing beginning issues with Python.

Comment: upvote for pointing out what might be the crux of the confusion: strings are iterable so they act like lists of chars.

Answer (score 61):

To append a string, just concatenate it with the `+` sign.

E.g.

```
>>> a = "Hello, "
>>> b = "world"
>>> str = a + b
>>> print str
Hello, world
```

`join` connects strings together with a separator. The separator is what you
place right before the `join`. E.g.

```
>>> "-".join([a,b])
'Hello, -world'
```

Join takes a list of strings as a parameter.

Comment: This kind of direct and concise answer should be advocated by our community. @Dan

Answer (score 8):

join() is for concatenating all list elements. For concatenating just two strings "+" would make more sense:

```
strid = repr(595)
print array.array('c', random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 20 - len(strid)))
    .tostring() + strid
```

Answer (score 4):

To expand a bit more on what others are saying, if you wanted to use join to simply concatenate your two strings, you would do this:

```
strid = repr(595)
print ''.join([array.array('c', random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 20 - len(strid)))
    .tostring(), strid])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a good explanation of why it is costly to use `+` for concatenating a large number of strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043636/any-reason-not-to-use-to-concatenate-two-strings)

> Plus operator is perfectly fine solution to concatenate **two** Python
>   strings. But if you keep adding more than two strings (n > 25) , you
>   might want to think something else.
>
> `''.join([a, b, c])` trick is a performance optimization.

Answer (score 0):

On providing this as input ,

```
li = ['server=mpilgrim', 'uid=sa', 'database=master', 'pwd=secret']
s = ";".join(li)
print(s)
```

Python returns this as output :

```
'server=mpilgrim;uid=sa;database=master;pwd=secret'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["my", "name", "is", "kourosh"]   
" ".join(list)
```

If this is an input, using the JOIN method, we can add the distance between the words and also convert the list to the string.

This is Python output

```
'my name is kourosh'
```

Answer (score 0):

**"".join** may be used to copy the string in a list to a variable

```
>>> myList = list("Hello World")
>>> myString = "".join(myList)
>>> print(myList)
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> print(myString)
Hello World
```