# How to split a string into a list by digits?

Tags: python

I have been looking for a way to split a string by digits, for instance:

```
st = "abc4ert"
from string import digits
st = st.split(digits)
--> st = ['abc','ert']
```

Is there a way to do that (without including the numbers in the list)?

Comment: added a non-regex approach to the dupes answers.

Comment: I think the question is not a duplicate. Isn't the situation in the linked question different?

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

st = "abc4ert"
print(re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+", st))
```

**Output:**

```
['abc', 'ert']
```

Comment: It would be great if you explain this one liner `re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+", st)`. It would be helpful to understand how it works for a larger audience reading your answer now and in the future

Comment: That's very basic regex literacy.`[...]` matches a single character which is one of the characters defined between the square brackets, and `A-Z` and `a-z` are character ranges whose semantics should be obvious.  The `+` matches a sequence of one or more matches on the immediately preceding expression.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

st = "abc4ert"
st = re.split(r'\d+', st)
print(st)
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'ert']
```