# How does os.path.join() work?

Tags: python, macos, path, built-in

Please help me understand how the builtin os.path.join() function works. For example:

```
import os
print os.path.join('cat','dog') # 'cat/dog' no surprise here
print os.path.join('cat','dog').join('fish') # 'fcat/dogicat/dogscat/dogh'
```

On Mac (and i guess linux too) os.name is an alias for posixpath. So looking into the posixpath.py module, the join() function looks like this:

```
def join(a, *p):
"""Join two or more pathname components, inserting '/' as needed.
If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components
will be discarded.  An empty last part will result in a path that
ends with a separator."""
path = a
for b in p:
    if b.startswith('/'):
        path = b
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
        path +=  b
    else:
        path += '/' + b
return path
```

So join() returns a string. Why does os.path.join('something').join('something else') even work? Shouldn't it raise something like 'str' object has no attribute 'join'? I mean if I copy the function some other place and call it like renamed_join('foo','bar') it works as expected but if i do renamed_join('foo','bar').renamed_join('foobar') will raise an AttributeError as expected. Hopefully this is not a very stupid question. It struck me just when I thought I was starting to understand python...

Comment: For more understanding check the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/explain-python-join)

Comment: You **can** say: `os.path.join('cat','dog','fish')` and get reasonable behavior.

Comment: "Shouldn't it raise something like `'str' object has no attribute 'join'`?" No. Python is not a liar...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't chain `os.path.join` like that. `os.path.join` returns a string; calling the `join` method of that calls the regular string [`join` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), which is entirely unrelated.

Comment: So it was all a fortunate names coincidence. Thank you for clearing this for me!

Answer (score 8):

Your second `join` call is not `os.path.join`, it is `str.join`. What this one does is that it joins the argument (as an iterable, meaning it can be seen as `f, i, s, h`) with self as the separator (in your case, `cat/dog`)

So basically, is puts `cat/dog` between every letter of `fish`.

Because `str` has a join attribute.