# password generator using Python

Tags: python

i got a program from one of the site to make password generator.

```
import string
from random import *
characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits
password =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(8, 16)))
print password
```

can someone explain what would be stored in "password" variable? would it be a value with a combination of upper,lower case,punctuation and digits with any length btwn 8 and 16?

is there any easier way to make password generator using python program?

Comment: what exactly the double quotes and dot does?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/explain-python-join#

Comment: What happened when you ran the code?

Comment: it is generating the random passwords.

Comment: Python ha fairly good documentation if you ever want to check what a function does, https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: still am i dont have complete idea what exactly the lines from random import * and password =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(8, 16)))  do..

Comment: @Maverick you can remedy that by learning Python.

Comment: Its clear now..how it works..thnk u all for suggestions and response...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print `characters` you will get a list of characters and symbols.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~0123456789
```

The next line is going to use this assortment of characters to randomly select from.  Adding or removing characters would allow you to customize the characters that make up the password.

You can read up on the `join`, `choice` and `randint` functions with a quick google search.  It might make more sense if this code was broken up into more lines and variables.  There's quite a bit of short hand smushed into a single line.

```
import string
import random
characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits

password = ""
password_length = random.randint(8, 16)

for x in range(password_length):
    char = random.choice(characters)
    password = password + char

print password
```

Comment: what is the use of giving from random import * ? can i give it just 'import random' ?

Comment: you can use import random and that is the more pythonic way to do things... that way you know what methods come from what library.  If you us `import random`  you would need to change `choice` to `random.choice`.  See revised answer.

Comment: initially there would be null value stored in password variable?

Comment: @ abaldwin99..thnk u for ur input

Comment: The password variable is an empty string initially.  Python has a value of `None` but an empty string is inherently different from that.

Comment: Folks,i have 1 more questions... how can i include only few special characters instead of using string.punctuation? for example i want to include only !@#$% in password generator...