# printing parts of a string while skipping others in Python

Tags: python

Say I have the following code:

`myVariable = "goodmorning"`

I can slice it with e.g. `myVariable[1:2]` (like Paolo Bergantino said here: [Is there a way to substring a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)), but how can I print some of the characters while jumping over others? e.g. how can I make it print **"gdorn"**? I tried `myVariable[0,3,5,6,7]` (which is wrong as it turns out) and I was thinking to myself that, if `myVariable[0,3,5,6,7]` worked then maybe `myVariable[0,3,5:7]` would work as well *(I hope you see my reasoning)*, which it doesn't. I am learning Python through *codecademy* and I didn't cover *functions* yet, in case you go into functions and such so if there is something easier like what I tried then I would be appreciate it if you explain it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```python
myVariable = 'iheoiahwd'
idxs = [0, 3, 4, 6, 7]

myVariable = [myVariable[i] for i in idxs] 
print ''.join(myVariable)
```

Or simplified to a one liner:

```
print ''.join([myVariable[i] for i in [0, 3, 4, 6, 7]])
```

Comment: ahh better than my suggestion ... :P

Comment: the letter **i**, can it be anything? And is **.join()** used for concatenating large number of things (like +, but better. just read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/explain-python-join ) and the string before **.join** if I introduce a space or whatever inside of it, will it also be printed, or the quotes mean something else here?

Comment: When you iterate over something such as a list, at each step the letter 'i' (could be renamed to j, k, banana or whatever) would refer to the current item. ''.join basically takes a list and sticks all the items together with a seperator. In this case there is no seperator '', resulting in no gaps. If your original list had a space in it as in ' ' then the space would survive. To experiment try using ' no_way '.join(somelist) to see what happens. .join should also be much faster than using + for lists anyway

Comment: Yes, it worked just as you said and I tried it in http://labs.codecademy.com/#:workspace.  I heard that there are different versions of Python but I'll assume this will be pretty much the same. Also, my original code that made me think of this question was myBanana = "Banana", tried to make it print **Bna** (banana buddies!)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_indices = [1,2,5,6,9]
print "".join(x for i,x in enumerate(my_string) if i in my_indices)
```

is one way you could do this

you could also use numpy

```
print "".join(numpy.array(list(my_string))[my_indices])
```

this would let you do weird things like

```
my_indices = [1,2,3,4,9,9,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as

```
myVariable = "goodmorning"
print (myVariable[0] + myVariable[3] + myVariable[5]  + myVariable[6] + myVariable[7] )
```

which outputs "gdorn".

It's not elegant.  It simply builds up the string one substring at a time.