# Mongo to Postgres connector error

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to extract data from MongoDB and write back it to Postgres. The following script works fine but string inserting as individual character which contains multiple entry.

For example: Instead of

> 'Apple' its inserting 'A', 'P', 'P' ,'L' ,'E'

```
for line in results:
    name = line['name']
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO xyz(Column1) VALUES('%s')""" % \
                (line['name']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `name` is a list `['A', 'P', 'P', 'L', 'E']` then you can combine it into a single string with the string method [`join`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/explain-python-join):

```
name = ''.join(list['name'])
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO xyz(Column1) VALUES('%s')""" %name)
```

Note that your original code doesn't use the name variable you've created.

Comment: You're welcome @jmc, thanks for marking it answered.