# convert python list to tsv format for input in memsql

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I am trying to convert below list to tsv format.

```
[1518785613920, 1, 19, 3099, 'abc', 0, 'def']
```

I want below format. I tried to do using loop but it's removing single quotes from Strings. With join also it is removing single quotes.

```
1518785613920, 1, 19, 3099, 'abc', 0, 'def'
```

Comment: So, you want the single quotes to show in the final tsv?

Comment: Yes. TSV is input format for memsql.

Answer (score 3):

The "single quotes" python is displaying when showing you the strings inside a list are just markers for "this is a string". If you need them as output, you can simply add singleticks to your string itself - it will then be displayed with doubleticks:

```
print([1,"'some data'",2,4))            # no deref, will be printed as repr(list).
print(*[1,"'some data'",2,4], sep=", ") # *[..] will deref elements+ print each with sep=","
```

Output:

```
[1, "'some data'", 2, 4] 
1, 'some data', 2, 4
```

You can simply include the single ticks in your output:

```
data = [1518785613920, 1, 19, 3099, 'abc', 0, 'def']

# generator expression that adds '' around strings in the generator and prints it 
# using the deref * and print's sep=", " specifier
print( *(x if not isinstance(x,str) else "'{}'".format(x) for x in data), sep=", ")
```

Output:

```
 1518785613920, 1, 19, 3099, 'abc', 0, 'def'
```

If you want to write it into a file, you can construct an output like so:

```
# use join() and some generator comp to create output. join needs strings so str(int)
s = ', '.join((str(x) if not isinstance(x,str) else "'{}'".format(x) for x in data))
# s is identical to above output
```

As mentioned by MadPhysicist thats about the same as

```
s = repr(data).strip("[]")
```

---

Doku [for  `print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)
Doku [for `join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) or search SO, f.e. here: [What exactly does the .join() method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/what-exactly-does-the-join-method-do)

Comment: Why not just use repr?

Comment: I mean that `str(x) if not isinstance(x,str) else "'{}'".format(x)` is basically just `repr(x)` for the values given here. Sorry my comment wasn't clear.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  `s = repr([1518785613920, 1, 19, 3099, 'abc', 0, 'def'])`  is  `[1518785613920, 1, 19, 3099, 'abc', 0, 'def']`  - inclusively the starting `[` and ending `]` which would have to be removed - you could do `repr(data).strip("[]")` - valid point

Comment: Not really what I'm saying. I'm saying to do `', '.join(map(repr, data))` or so. The long conditional expression *inside* the generator is what I'm suggesting you can shorten.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) which:

1. Comes with the standard library
2. Covers various edge-cases with quotes in your strings

Together with [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) it will allow you to build in-memory string which you can pass further.