# Swaping letters in a 2+ word string

Tags: python, string, list

Let´s say I have a one-word string ("Hello") and I wanted to swap the first and last letter so I´d do this:

```
s="Hello"
l=list(s)
l[0],l[len(l)-1]=l[len(l)-1],l[0]
print("".join(l))
```

But, what if I had to swap the first and last letter in every word of the string:"Hello World" , so that I would get "oellH dorlW".

I was thinking using nested lists but it seems overcomplicated.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  How do you separate words of a sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so you can create a new one by slicing:

```
s = "Hello"
>>> s[-1] + s[1:-1] + s[0]
"oellH"
```

To do multiple words, split and rejoin as follows:

```
s= "Hello World"
>>> ' '.join(word[-1] + word[1:-1] + word[0] for word in s.split())
'oellH dorlW'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split your string, swap letters for each word and .join() it back together:

```
# example is wrong, does not swap, only puts first in the back. see below for fix
text = ' '.join( t[1:]+t[0] for t in "Hello World".split() )
print (text)
```

Output:

```
 elloH orldW
```

This uses list comprehensionst to extract each splitted word (`t`) - list slicing to move the front letter to its back (`t[1:]+t[0]`) and `' '.join()` to make the list of strings back to a string.

Links:

- [What exactly does the .join() method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/what-exactly-does-the-join-method-do)  and [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) (for lists, strings are similar)
- [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

It also works for longer strings:

```
elloH orldW si a eallyr verusedo trings ermt - orF ureS !
```

---

As pointed out by @Accumulation I misread the question - my example simply puts the first letter to the end of the string  thats only halve the work done for swapping first and last letter:

```
# t[-1] is the last character put to the front, 
# followed by t[1:-1] 1st to (but not including) the last character 
# followed by t[0] the first character
text = ' '.join( t[-1]+t[1:-1]+t[0] for t in "Hello World".split() )
print (text)
```

Output:

```
oellH dorlW
```

Comment: Elegant! Would definitely take a few lines for Java

Comment: The OP wants "oellH dorlW", not "elloH orldW".

Comment: Yeah, I was actually looking for something a bit different but I totally get your logic,thanks for the references too

Comment: His example is perfectly consistent with the wording of the question. Even without the example, I would interpret "swap the first and last letter" as `final_string[first],final_string[last = initial_string[last],initial_string[first]`. Perhaps you should add the possibility that your understanding of "swap" is incorrect to your list of hypotheses.

Comment: @Acccumulation - fixed it, misread it - thanks for putting my hesitent nose into it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    string  = "Hello Planet Earth"
```

Make a list of words by splitting on space char

```
    words = string.split(" ")
```

Then iterate on that list with your script

```
    for word in words:
        l = list(word)
        l[0], l[len(l) - 1] = l[len(l) - 1], l[0]
        print("".join(l))
```