# Remove elements from delimited string in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I have the following string for example:

```
a-b-c-d-e-f
```

I want to remove the first element and the last two elements so the output will be:

```
b-c-d
```

I tried to use `rsplit`, But the output is list:

```
print string.rsplit('-',)[1:-2]
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

How can i combine the list element back to be a string? Is there any easier way to remove the elements instead of using `rsplit`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1876211/3462319

Comment: string = '-'.join(new_string)   where new_string is the split list

Comment: Thanks guys. Works great!

Comment: Here's [another website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/) that explains str.join, even using your delimiters.

Comment: @gofvonx, I don't think this is a dupe of that one, simply because the approach for the answer is so different. This question comes with no knowledge of the function, so finding the one you referenced might be difficult. That being said. I think there is value in reading through some of the [language documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) surrounding a question before asking it here.

Answer (score 4):

You can just combine calls to split and rsplit:

```
a = "a-b-c-d-e-f"
b = a.split("-", 1)[-1].rsplit("-", 2)[0]
```

But that is just for the "cool puzzle effect".
The more maintainable approach is certainly to split the string at the `-` separator, operate on the data as a list, and then use `join` to assemble it back:

```
a = "a-b-c-d-e-f"
b = a.split("-")
c = b[1:-2]
d = "-".join(c)
```

Or everything run together, if you prefer:

```
b = "-".join(a.split("-")[1:-2])
```

Answer (score 1):

rsplit returns the list, you need to join the elements of the returned list with '-' to get the desired result.

```
'-'.join(string.rsplit('-',)[1:-2])
```