# Python- Joining the list items in a text file

Tags: python, list, join, file-handling

I have a text file in which i wrote a list. Now i want to join all the list items in that text file. Here is the screenshot of the contents of text file [image: The content of my text file]

I tried doing this:

```
    file = open("Result.txt","r+",encoding="utf8")
    text = file.read()
    text.join(' ')
```

but it prints ' '

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly does the .join() method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/what-exactly-does-the-join-method-do)

Comment: That file in your screenshot isn't `Result.txt`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes i took the screenshot of output in the jupyter notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse the file content with `ast.literal_eval` to turn it into an actual list first, and then use the `str.join` method to join the list items into one string:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("Result.txt","r+",encoding="utf8") as file, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write(' '.join(literal_eval(file.read())))
```

Comment: but it doesn't change the contents of the file.. how to update the file or write it to a new text file? @blhsing

Comment: I've updated my answer with how you can write the output to a new text file `output.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You are given a string.

trim the brackets with

```
text = text[1:-1]
```

Then remove the "'" and ","

```
text.replace("'", "").replace(",","")
```

You can also remove the '\\n' the same way.

Comment: i was using join because i want to join the words in a sentence but separate the sentences from each other from making the use of \n