# Custom variable names when reshaping pandas dataframe from long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I have the following dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
silly = pd.DataFrame({'id':[i for i in range(3) for j in range(3)], 'cat':['a','b','c'] * 3, 'v1':np.random.random(9), 'v2':np.random.random(9)})
print(silly)

   id cat        v1        v2
0   0   a  0.374509  0.211018
1   0   b  0.132380  0.996551
2   0   c  0.194045  0.956656
3   1   a  0.475134  0.892442
4   1   b  0.166790  0.615519
5   1   c  0.285272  0.896530
6   2   a  0.397225  0.147312
7   2   b  0.504841  0.679368
8   2   c  0.595551  0.625830
```

I need to transform this data from long to wide format. To do this, I tried:

```py
silly_wide = silly.pivot(index='id', columns='cat', values=['v1','v2'])
print(silly_wide)

           v1                            v2                    
cat         a         b         c         a         b         c
id                                                             
0    0.374509  0.132380  0.194045  0.211018  0.996551  0.956656
1    0.475134  0.166790  0.285272  0.892442  0.615519  0.896530
2    0.397225  0.504841  0.595551  0.147312  0.679368  0.625830
```

This works, but I need to "flatten" the column names in order to get custom column names. The desired result should look like this:

```
id         v1a       v1b       v1c       v2a       v2b       v2c                                                            
 0    0.374509  0.132380  0.194045  0.211018  0.996551  0.956656
 1    0.475134  0.166790  0.285272  0.892442  0.615519  0.896530
 2    0.397225  0.504841  0.595551  0.147312  0.679368  0.625830
```

Is there a parameter in `pandas.DataFrame.pivot()` that can help? How can this be done otherwise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - How to flatten a hierarchical index in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns)

Comment: add a `values`: `silly_wide = silly.pivot(index='id', columns='cat', values='value')`

Comment: `silly.pivot(index='id', columns='cat', values='value').rename_axis(None, axis=1)` or  `silly_wide.columns = silly_wide.columns.to_series().str.join('_')`

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi It does although I did not entirely understand the code and I believe the `.strip()` is redundant. I also did not realize this was actually called "flattening an index".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> silly.pivot(values='value', columns='cat', index='id').add_prefix('value_')
cat   value_a   value_b   value_c
id                               
0    0.207024  0.412420  0.001094
1    0.990861  0.386278  0.092327
2    0.093256  0.984317  0.721615
```

With the revised data for multiple value columns, you can use a list comprehension to join the different levels in the column names:

```
silly_wide = silly.pivot(values=['v1', 'v2'], columns='cat', index='id')
silly_wide.columns = [''.join(col) for col in silly_wide.columns]
>>> silly_wide
         v1a       v1b       v1c       v2a       v2b       v2c
id                                                            
0   0.625485  0.846527  0.987203  0.261629  0.767406  0.138268
1   0.305565  0.151946  0.687424  0.460385  0.825205  0.768997
2   0.327507  0.215792  0.796235  0.018233  0.734781  0.423353
```

Comment: I changed the question slightly. I added another value column. Can `add_prefix()` be generalized to more columns?

Comment: What exactly does the .join() method do? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/what-exactly-does-the-join-method-do

Answer (score 0):

[pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_wider.html) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/index.html) may be helpful as an abstraction for reshaping from long to wide (it is a wrapper around pd.pivot):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn
df.pivot_wider(index='id', names_from='cat', names_sep="")
 
   id       v1a       v1b       v1c       v2a       v2b       v2c
0   0  0.374509  0.132380  0.194045  0.211018  0.996551  0.956656
1   1  0.475134  0.166790  0.285272  0.892442  0.615519  0.896530
2   2  0.397225  0.504841  0.595551  0.147312  0.679368  0.625830
```