# How to print out the list items horizontally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like this:

```
['0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '9']
```

I would like to print the items like :

```
0111234579
```

Can someone help how should I print out the items as I showed?

Thank you

Comment: `print(*list, sep='')`

Comment: As a matter of fact, this is horizontal.

Comment: "vertically" means printing each item *below* the previous. Printing each item *to the right* of the previous is "horizontally". Which orientation do you actually need – the one from the title or the one from the example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does the .join() method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/what-exactly-does-the-join-method-do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list1 = ['0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '9']
print("".join(list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(" ".join(arr))
```

Here `arr` is your list

Answer (score 0):

it's easy

```
a=['0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '9']
for i in a:
    print(i,end="")
```

write `print(i,end=" ")` 
if you want a space between the elements.
or try `print(*a,sep="")`

Answer (score -1):

use join list

```
list=[s ,o ,m ,e ,i ,t ,e, m ,s]
joinedlist="".join(list)
print(x) # prints with no spaces

# # # # with spaces # # # #
spacelist=" ".join(list)
print(spacelist)
```