# how to find its the last item in for loop ,when read from file - Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to read from the `pList.csv` file and write all item in a string, such that each row is separated by a comma.

the file has only one column. for example, the `pList.csv`  is :

> 28469977
>
> 24446384
>
> 25968054

and output string must be:
`28469977,24446384,25968054`

for do this, have considered the following code. but there is a little problem

```
p_list = ""
with open("pList.csv", mode="r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        p_list += row[0]
        if its_not_last_loop :
            p_list += ","
```

What expression is appropriate for `its_not_last_loop` so that `,` is not applied to the last row of the file?

Comment: You are looking for `str.join`. For example: `",".join(["hello", "world", "foo", "bar"])` returns `'hello,world,foo,bar'`.

Comment: Thank you @PaulM. this solution handles my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("pList.csv", mode="r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    out_list = []
    for row in reader:
        out_list.append(row[0]) #row[0] get value for the sample input
    p_list = ",".join(out_list)
    print(p_list)
```

See [What exactly does the .join() method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/what-exactly-does-the-join-method-do)

Answer (score 0):

This can be shortened to (and is faster)

```
with open("pList.csv", mode="r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    p_list = ",".join(row[0] for row in reader)
    print(p_list)
```