# Inserting string to string regularly ( 1234567891234 -> 1,2345,6789,1234 )

Tags: python, string

How to insert ' # ' for each n index from backward?
ex) n=4
`evil = '01234567891234oooooooooooooooo321'`
to
`stan = '0#1234#5678#9123#4ooo#oooo#oooo#oooo#o321'`
i tried using list with for,if statement, got stuck. something shameful like this

```
a = 1234567891234
b = [ a[-i] for i in range(1,len(a)+1)]
for i in range(len(b)):
    c += b[i]
    if i%4==0: #stuck
        c += ',' 
c.reverse()
```

What is the optimum way?

Comment: Could you add some of the code you've tried to question?

Comment: why is there a `#` after the first `0`?

Comment: it's from backward, please see first line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/what-exactly-does-the-join-method-do, can you see how to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you actually want to insert `#`, or `,`? *Why* do you want to do this? If it's to format a number for some locale, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators help?

Comment: Thank you, i was just curious about how f'{value:,}' works like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cut the string into chunks (backwards) and then concat them using the seperator

```
evil = '01234567891234oooooooooooooooo321'
l = 4
sep = '#'
sep.join([evil[max(i-l,0):i] for i in range(len(evil), 0, -l)][::-1])
```

```
'0#1234#5678#9123#4ooo#oooo#oooo#oooo#o321'
```

Comment: This isn't the desired result?

Comment: the request is to do it backward. A slight modification on the indexes and it will work :)

Comment: did not see the reverse thing. updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might use a pattern asserting optional repetitions of 4 characters to the right, and replace that position with `#`

```
import re

pattern = r"(?=(?:.{4})*$)"
s = "01234567891234oooooooooooooooo321"
print(re.sub(pattern, "#", s))
```

Output

```
0#1234#5678#9123#4ooo#oooo#oooo#oooo#o321#
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/nYuZfV)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
evil = '01234567891234oooooooooooooooo321'
''.join(j if i%4  else f'#{j}' for i, j in enumerate(evil[::-1]))[::-1][:-1]
```

Output:

```
'0#1234#5678#9123#4ooo#oooo#oooo#oooo#o321'
```

Answer (score 0):

`chunks` function as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/9296093)

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

evil = '01234567891234oooooooooooooooo321'
n = 4
stan = "#".join(chunks(evil[::-1], n))[::-1]
print(stan) # Output: 0#1234#5678#9123#4ooo#oooo#oooo#oooo#o321
```

Input string is reversed (`[::-1]`), split into chunks, joined by "#" and then reversed back again. (It's possible to skip reverses if you calculate how many characters there will be in the first set of characters)

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution would be using parts of `evil` string:

```py
evil = '01234567891234oooooooooooooooo321'
n = 4
start = len(evil) % n
insert = '#'

stan = evil[:start] + insert
for i in range(start, len(evil) - n, n):
    stan += evil[i:i+n] + insert
stan += evil[-n:]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would go backwards through your string `evil` by reversing the string and iterating through it in a for loop. Then I set a count variable to keep track of how many loops it's done, and reset to 0 when it equals 4. All of this looks like the below:

```
count = 0
for char in evil[::-1]:
    if count == 4:
        count = 0
    count += 1
```

You can then establish a new empty string (`new_str`), and append each character of `evil` to, each time checking if count is 4, and adding a # to the string as well before resetting the count. Full code:

```
count = 0
new_str = ''
for char in evil[::-1]:
    if count == 4:
        new_str += '#'
        count = 0
    count += 1
    new_str += char
```

This will produce the new string reversed, so you need to reverse it again to get the desired result:

```
new_str = new_str[::-1]
```

Output:

```
'123o#oooo#oooo#oooo#ooo4#3219#8765#4321#0'
```

Answer (score 0):

An exact method: use `divmod` to get the reminder and quotient of the string when divided in "blocks" of size 4 then slice.

```
evil = '01234567891234oooooooooooooooo321'

size = 4
q, r = divmod(len(evil), size)
sep = '#'
stan = f"{evil[:r]}{sep}{sep.join(evil[r+i*size: r+(i+1)*size] for i in range(q))}"

print(stan)
```

Remark: if the length of the string is a multiple of the block's size the new string will start with `sep`. Assumed as default behavior since lake of explanation